# -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:]

Tags: ios, uiprintinteractioncntrler, uiprintinfo

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
<UIPrintPanelNavigationController: 0x144010a00> is pushing the same view controller instance (<UIPrinterBrowserViewController: 0x142854400>) more than once which is not supported and is most likely an error in the application : com.myapp.myapp

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0xec870 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2bc00 objc_exception_throw
2  UIKitCore                      0xcb284 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:]
3  UIKitCore                      0xca398 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:]
4  PrintKitUI                     0x45024 -[UIPrintPanelNavigationController pushViewController:animated:]
5  UIKitCore                      0x129b78 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:]
6  UIKitCore                      0x129680 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext _runAlongsideCompletions]
7  UIKitCore                      0x128d10 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:]
8  UIKitCore                      0x7a3d48 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke_5
9  UIKitCore                      0x84a38 __UIVIEW_IS_EXECUTING_ANIMATION_COMPLETION_BLOCK__
10 UIKitCore                      0x841d0 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:]
11 UIKitCore                      0x83848 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:]
12 UIKitCore                      0x65aa4 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
13 UIKitCore                      0x65bb8 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
14 QuartzCore                     0x72098 run_animation_callbacks(void*)
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x12998 _dispatch_main_queue_drain
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x125b0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
18 CoreFoundation                 0x3720c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
19 CoreFoundation                 0x33f18 __CFRunLoopRun
20 CoreFoundation                 0x33668 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
21 GraphicsServices               0x35ec GSEventRunModal
22 UIKitCore                      0x22c2b4 -[UIApplication _run]
23 UIKitCore                      0x22b8f0 UIApplicationMain
24 MyApp                          0x4a940 main + 14 (main.m:14)
25 ???                            0x1ac55adcc (Missing)
```

I found this crash in Firebase crashlytics.

**This is device info**
Model:iPad Air (5th generation)
Version:17.1.1
Orientation:Landscape

Please help me to findout the root cause of the crash and possible solution.

I have tried to reprduce the crash but didn't reproduce.